# How to your declare a computed getter which is an aggregate of observable list with mobx

Tags: angular, mobx

I have a class hierarchy of projects => task_lists => tasks each array being @observable. Now I want to create a "@computed get allTasks" from project which aggregates all tasks from all task_lists of the project.

```
class MsiTask {
    @observable name:string;
    constructor () {.... };
}
class MsiTaskList {
    @observable tasks:MsiTask[];
    constructor () {.... };
}

class MsiProject {
            id:string;
            @observable name:string;
            @observable taskLists:MsiTaskList[]=[];

            constructor (data) {
                    $log.debug ('Constructing a Project with', data, this);

                    this.id = data.id;
                    this.name = data.name;

                    ProjectCache[this.id] = this;

                    /** Can I do reassign taskLists or should I fill it? **/
                    this.taskLists = lodash.map (data.taskLists || [], (taskList) => {
                            return new MsiTaskList (taskList, this);
                    });


            }

            createTaskList (title:string) : MsiTaskList {
                    let taskList = new MsiTaskList ({ name: title, id: MsiUtils.uuid() }, this);
                    $log.debug ('add task list', title, taskList);
                    this.taskLists.push (taskList);
                    return taskList;
            }

 }
```

I currently define it this way:

in class MsiProject ...

```
@computed get allTasks () : MsiTask[] {
   var arrayOfTasks = lodash.map(this.taskLists, 'tasks');
   var result = lodash.reduce(arrayOfTasks, (res, array) => {
         lodash.each (array, (it) => { res.push(it); });
         return res;
   }, []);
   return result; // tried also return observable.array (result);
 }
```

but I am getting a digest cycle error when used in my custom component:

I understand that allTasks returns a different array each time but my thought was mobx will see that its content has not changed and not generate a digest cycle.

Am I completely not understanding how to use mobx?

Comment: Could you please include the entire `MsiProject` class, the component, and a stack trace of the error?

Comment: Thanks @Tholle. I added some code to MsiProjects. While looking at it and re-reading the FAQ it occurred to me that I was reassigning in the constructor this.taskLists which is problably the problem. I should problably fill it. (I will have to try but since I changed my code in my program). What do you think? Is that the problem. Should I wrap it with a new observable. Would that mess the decorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `observable.array` implements the entire array API, but is actually not an array under the hood, so it is best to use the built in utility functions instead of lodash. Don't overwrite the reference to the array, use [**replace**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html) instead.

**Example ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/rurunemipe/edit?js,output))**

```
class MsiTaskList {
  @observable tasks = [];
  constructor(tasks) {
    this.tasks.replace(tasks);
  }
}

class MsiProject {
  id = '';
  @observable name = '';
  @observable taskLists = [];

  constructor(id, name, taskLists) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    const lists = taskLists.map(list => new MsiTaskList(list));
    this.taskLists.replace(lists);
  }

  @computed get allTasks() {
    return this.taskLists.reduce((result, list) => {
      list.tasks.forEach(task => result.push(task));
      return result;
    }, []);
  }
}
```